# ValueError: "ResizeBilinear" op: the second input, which is the output size, must have elements of type int32

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, coreml

I am using Keras from tensorflow 2.2.0. I have a model with several UpSampling2D layers with bilinear interpolations. When trying to convert the model using CoreML 4.0, I get the following error:

> ValueError: "ResizeBilinear" op: the second input, which is the output size, must have elements of type int32

When the UpSampling2D interpolation is nearest the export works. Still I want the interpolation to be 'bilinear'

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in coremltools. In situations like these, I would (temporarily) change the model to use "nearest" just so that you can do the conversion, then patch up the mlmodel file afterwards to change the type of this layer to "bilinear". You can do this with coremltools and the protobuf API (see my book).